# Resources not loading on the webpage

Tags: html, css, nginx, server

I wrote simple HTML and CSS files and uploaded them to my server, however, those CSS and HTML files are not being read properly. It works fine when I test it locally but it does not work when I upload it to my server.

Here is my tree:

```
.
|-- assets
|   `-- icon.png
|-- index.html
|-- pages
|   |-- about.html
|   |-- certificates.html
|   |-- programmingLanguages.html
|   |-- projects.html
|   `-- socials.html
`-- styles
    |-- base_style.css
    `-- indexpage.css
```

I've tried "/styles/indexpage.css", "./styles/indexpage.css" and "syles/indexpage.css".
I even tried the absolute path with "/var/www/suchicodes/styles/indexpage.css" and none of these work...

Please help.
The webpage:
suchicodes.info

Comment: I tested on my code -> i believe "styles/indexpage.css" should work fine, not "syles...." one provided. If that doesnt fix your issue feel free to share some of your code

Comment: That was just a typo... It was styles/indexpage.css.  Just go to the website for the code?

Answer (score 1):

May be on the server the .htaccess is changing the requested path. You should use dynamically builded path, for example url('/styles/indexpage.css') which is converted like `www.mysite.com/styles/indexpage.css`

Comment: But it's not just the css file. When I add an anchor tag to programming.html, the URL in the browser is perfect: xyz.com/pages/programming.html but it still returns a 404 not found error